# load database from text file

Tags: database, load, text-files

say I have a table named XY_values with columns X_values and Y_values.

now, I have a text file xy.txt which contains those x values and y values, with x values in the 1st column and y values in the second column.

is there any SQL command to load those x and y values from the text file into the XY_values table in the database?

thanks.

Comment: What database? It really depends what database generally. Although there probably is some general tools which use odbc/jdbc or something to load them.

Comment: This varies between DBMSs. Can you be more specific about your platform?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL Server has an import facility which can read text files and import them as tables, or even send them off to another datasource. In fact, I remember quite a few managers buying SQL 7 on the strength of that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using [SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) to do this.  [Here is a good link](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/ssis-importing-data-from-a-text-file-using-a-package/) that goes over importing data from a text file using SSIS.

Comment: see 
http://support.modwest.com/content/6/253/en/how-do-i-import-delimited-data-into-mysql.html
I am using MySQL database, but regardless whether MySQL or MS SQL Server, it should work.

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/importfile.txt' 
INTO TABLE test_table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(field1, filed2, field3); 

Above is for fields terminated by comma, how about fields terminated by space?
I try this, but it does not work, why?
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '